# Restrict azure application only to get access by custom domain name

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cdn

I can access my azure website using

1. Custom domain name (`*.net`)
2. Azure default website (`*azurewebsite.net`)
3. CDN Endpoint url (`*.azureedge.net`), it has origin as azure website url

Is there a way to force end user to use only Option 1, not by options 2 and 3.

Comment: Check the hostname in your application and redirect the user to the correct domain.

Comment: @Dan Wilson
How CDN will work if I redirect to custom domain? It will always try to get content frim origin server instead of edges.

Answer (score 0):

If [Azure traffic Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-overview) is possible, I recommand that you could use the Azure traffic management to do that. Then you could forward to Azure traffic Manager endpoint to your custom domain name from domain name supplier console. You also could refer to this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CGsXD-eUv0).

Take Godday for example:

[image]